# Python error trying to use mysql-connector-python library

Tags: python, raspbian, mysql-connector

Im working through the w3Schools example of connecting to a mysql database using python.

I'm running raspbian on a raspberry pi.

I've installed the mysql-connector-python library (done using sudo as well and both say it's already installed).

Then I go into the python REPL and try importing to test it but get an error saying it's missing.

[image]

Could someone point me to where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: It's `mysql.connector`